# Error while executing BCP Script - Must declare the scalar variable @v

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, bcp

Description: I have created a stored procedure which will create a pipe separated flat file for the range between from & to id's which are passed as parameters i.e. @from & @to.

The third parameter i.e. @v is a temp variable which will get the incremented value in the loop & this will be used in the where condition of the query.

When I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server, I get an error

> Must declare the scalar variable @v

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FlatFileCreate]
    @from INT, 
    @to INT,
    @v INT
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE(@from <= @to)
    BEGIN
        SET @v = @from;

        DECLARE @cmd varchar(2000)

        SET @cmd = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM SDB.dbo.Customer WHERE ID=@v  " queryout "c:\output_Aug27.txt" -c -T -t "|" -SOLA-DB'

        EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

        SET @from = @from + 1;  
    END
    RETURN 0
END
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your dynamic command there's no @v

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FlatFileCreate]
    @from INT, 
    @to INT,
    @v INT
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE(@from <= @to)
    BEGIN
        SET @v = @from;

        DECLARE @cmd varchar(2000)

        SET @cmd = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM SDB.dbo.Customer WHERE ID=' + CAST(@v AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '  " queryout "c:\output_Aug' + CAST(@v AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '.txt" -c -T -t "|" -SOLA-DB'

        EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

        SET @from = @from + 1;  
    END
    RETURN 0
END
```

Comment: It gave the error as "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'bcp "select * from SDB.dbo.Customer WHERE ID=' to data type int."

Comment: The modified query is as follows:                                                                                                      SET @cmd = 'bcp "select * from SDB.dbo.Customer WHERE ID='+@v +'  " queryout "c:\output_Aug27.txt" -c -T -t "|" -SOLA-DB'

Comment: @user3783406, Sorry, your @v is of type INT, it must be casted to varchar to be concatenated with the '+' sign...

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you please give an example or update that particular line which iv shard above?

Comment: One more point, there is - as far as I understand you, no need to pass in v, as you always take the value of from into v...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help it worked. One more small change, really appreciate if you can help out with this. Currently one file is generated i.e.output_Aug27.txt, now i wan to use the same @v value here also so different names can be assigned. E.g 3.txt, 4.txt & so on..

Comment: Please update the same line of code instead of a hardcoded file name, i would like to use the same @v value to be the file name & the extension as .txt as it is currently in the code.

Comment: @user3783406; just done... May be you want to take away the "output_Aug" before the inserted "v"-variable...

Comment: Appreciate your great help! Thanks